# Media query is not working as I expected, am I doing something wrong here?

Tags: html, css

I have used a media query on my webpage and included a meta tag in my html to make it responsive for smaller devices as follows:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){/*code for smartphones*/}
```

```html
<meta type='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0'>
```

NOTE: The media query code is to make the page viewable for smaller devices.

The problem is when I try running the code on the microsoft edge emulation tool or my **smartphone** the css code inside the media query does not run and as a result my webpage looks very small on small devices, the media query code only runs when I scale the browser window to a smaller size.
Please let me know how I should fix this so my webpage is responsive on all devices and tell me if I should elaborate more, any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: `the media query code only runs when I scale the browser window to a smaller size.` does this mean it is working ?

Comment: *the media query code only runs when I scale the browser window to a smaller size.*, this is literally the purpose of media query so that means its working dude

Comment: @TusharShahi yes it is working when I scale the browser window to a smaller size but it is not responsive on phones, that is what I want: to make the code run on smart phones as well so the website can be viewed on multiple devices

Comment: @Anoymouse The code is running when I resize the browser window but not on smaller devices like smart phones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally what I wanted to do was to make the webpage responsive for mobile phones rather than different browser window sizes, I guess I should have mentioned that explicitly. I fixed that issue by using max-device-width rather than max-width, thought I would just share this for anyone encountering the same problem.